# Query to identify vertices of Label "A" that have edges to multiple vertices of Label "B"

Tags: gremlin

I have a graph with vertices of label "organization" with edges to, among others, vertices of label "social_account". In this one-to-many relationship, an organization vertex should only have one social_account vertex per distinct social platform. That is to say that an organization can have edges to a "Twitter" social_account vertex, a "Medium" social_account vertex, and an "Instagram" social_account vertex, but it should not have edges to more than one "Twitter" social_account vertex, illustrated here:

[Toy data diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWKZD.jpg)

I'd like a query which identifies:

1. **organization** vertices with more than one **social_account** vertex for a given social platform
2. The IDs of the associated **social_account** vertices which should be dropped, based on their **updated_at** value.

I have the following query which returns the organization ID and the associated IDs of the social_account vertices to which the organization vertex has an edge.

```
g.V().hasLabel("organization").as("org", "social_ids").select("org", "social_ids").by(id).by(out().hasLabel('social_account').id().fold())
```

Given an input "Twitter" I would like to see something along the lines of this for the above toy data:

`[org: Org-2, to_drop: [Twitter-39]]`

and similar output for a general input corresponding to a **social_account** "social" property.

I'm relatively new to Gremlin so advice toward efficiently filtering these results to the desired output would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps a lot when you provide a traversal that builds the graph so we can give you a tested answer.

```
g.addV('Organization').property(id, 'Org-1').as('org1').
  addV('social_account').property(id, 'Twitter-01').property('social', 'Twitter').property('updated_at', 1234).as('twitter01').
  addE('has_social_account').from('org1').to('twitter01').
  addV('social_account').property(id, 'Medium-34').property('social', 'Medium').property('updated_at', 1345).as('medium34').
  addE('has_social_account').from('org1').to('medium34').
  addV('social_account').property(id, 'Insta-55').property('social', 'Instagram').property('updated_at', 4567).as('insta55').
  addE('has_social_account').from('org1').to('insta55').
  addV('Organization').property(id, 'Org-2').as('org2').
  addV('social_account').property(id, 'Twitter-39').property('social', 'Twitter').property('updated_at', 1111).as('twitter39').
  addE('has_social_account').from('org2').to('twitter39').
  addV('social_account').property(id, 'Twitter-60').property('social', 'Twitter').property('updated_at', 2345).as('twitter60').
  addE('has_social_account').from('org2').to('twitter60').
  addV('social_account').property(id, 'Insta-19').property('social', 'Instagram').property('updated_at', 4567).as('insta19').
  addE('has_social_account').from('org2').to('insta19')
```

And here is the traversal that gets the organizations having more than one Twitter account and the IDs of the Twitter accounts that need to be dropped.

```
g.V().hasLabel('Organization').where(out('has_social_account').has('social', 'Twitter').count().is(gt(1))).
  project('org', 'to_drop').
    by(id).
    by(out('has_social_account').has('social', 'Twitter').
      order().by('updated_at', desc).
      range(1, -1).id().fold())
```

The `where` step filters by the organizations having more than one Twitter account. And the `project` step gets the IDs of these organizations and their Twitter accounts that need to be deleted.

To get the Twitter accounts that need to be deleted, the nested traversal in the second `by` modulator gets the Twitter accounts associated with the organization, orders them based on the value of "updated_at" (descending). Then uses the `range` step to skip the first Twitter account which does not need to be deleted.